# VBA - Why is adding a collection to my loop giving me a type mismatch error?

Tags: vba, excel

I had a really really long, but functional, macro to change cell background colors based on variable thresholds. I thought, there's a 0% chance this is the best way to do this, so I tried to shove some of my variables (the ones for column number) into a collection and cycle through them. I won't make you suffer through the hundreds of lines of the original, but a brief section to illustrate:

```
For i = 14 To 43 

        If Cells(i, rc) = AMER Then

                If Cells(i, NU_C) <= (Cells(AM_R, NU_C) - pct) Then
                    Cells(i, NU_C).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219)
                Else

                    If Cells(i, NU_C).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219) Then
                    Cells(i, NU_C).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    End If

                End If

                If Cells(i, FW_C) <= (Cells(AM_R, FW_C) - pct) Then
                    Cells(i, FW_C).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219)
                Else

                    If Cells(i, FW_C).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219) Then
                    Cells(i, FW_C).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    End If

                End If
```

That worked fine, except the tears I cried whenever I had to change anything across all eighteen individual If sections. So here's the same part when I tried rewriting it with a collection:

```
For i = 14 To 43

                If Cells(i, rc) = AMER Then

                    For Each v In C

                        If Cells(i, v) <= (Cells(AM_R, v) - pct) Then
                            Cells(i, v).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219)
                        Else

                            If Cells(i, v).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219) Then
                            Cells(i, v).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                            End If

                        End If

                    Next v
```

I'll put the full new code at the bottom but anyway, when I try to run it I get an error 13 type mismatch, which highlights this line:

```
If Cells(i, v) <= (Cells(AM_R, v) - pct) Then
```

I'm assuming it's just highlighting that one because it's first, and that it's a more fundamental error than just a typo. I tried using [this page](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-type-mismatch/) to find what's wrong, but it doesn't seem to have my error. The method listed, of dropping the two sides into the Watch window, shows both Cells(i, v) and (Cells(AM_R, v) - pct) as "Variant/Integer" types.

The full code, which is still long but nowhere near as long as it once was:

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim rc As Integer
Dim pct As Range

rc = 3 'column


Set pct = Range("AA6")

'Columns
Dim NU_C As Integer
Dim FW_C As Integer
Dim BI_C As Integer
Dim B_C As Integer
Dim DB_C As Integer
Dim TL_C As Integer

NU_C = 9
FW_C = 12
BI_C = 15
B_C = 18
DB_C = 21
TL_C = 24

'Rows
Dim AM_R As Integer
Dim EM_R As Integer
Dim AS_R As Integer

AM_R = 6
EM_R = 7
AS_R = 8

'Regions
Dim AMER As Range
Dim EMEA As Range
Dim ASIA As Range
Set AMER = Cells(AM_R, rc)
Set EMEA = Cells(EM_R, rc)
Set ASIA = Cells(AS_R, rc)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim C As Collection

Set C = New Collection
C.Add "NU_C"
C.Add "FW_C"
C.Add "BI_C"
C.Add "B_C"
C.Add "DB_C"
C.Add "TL_C"

Dim v As Variant

        For i = 14 To 43

                If Cells(i, rc) = AMER Then

                    For Each v In C

                        If Cells(i, v) <= (Cells(AM_R, v) - pct) Then
                            Cells(i, v).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219)
                        Else

                            If Cells(i, v).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219) Then
                            Cells(i, v).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                            End If

                        End If

                    Next v

                ElseIf Cells(i, rc) = EMEA Then

                    For Each v In C

                        If Cells(i, v) <= (Cells(EM_R, v) - pct) Then
                            Cells(i, v).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219)
                        Else

                            If Cells(i, v).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219) Then
                            Cells(i, v).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                            End If

                        End If

                    Next v

            ElseIf Cells(i, rc) = ASIA Then

                    For Each v In C

                        If Cells(i, v) <= (-pct) Then
                            Cells(i, v).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219)
                        Else

                            If Cells(i, v).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 220, 219) Then
                            Cells(i, v).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                            End If

                        End If

                    Next v

            End If

        Next i


End Sub
```

Could someone please explain to me what I'm missing? I'd really appreciate it! 
Also, as an aside, am I asking too many questions on this site? I don't want to take advantage and it's not like I can give back by answering questions because I'm not a programmer and I don't know what I'm doing :\

Comment: Your collection contains strings, which are neither column numbers nor letters. `Cells(i, "NU_C")` makes no sense.

Comment: From Google it seemed like Collections can contain VBA objects, which I assumed meant they could contain variables. Is there something I should be using other than a collection? Dictionary?

Comment: It can, but you added strings explicitly. You'd need `C.Add NU_C` without the quotes. An array would be less overhead here than a collection.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I guess I thought it needed the quotes like Range("A1") needs quotes. I'll look into the arrays, too.

Comment: If you wrote your comment as an answer I could give you a check mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding string literals to your collection, rather than the variables you intended. You should use:

```
Set C = New Collection
C.Add NU_C
C.Add FW_C
C.Add BI_C
C.Add B_C
C.Add DB_C
C.Add TL_C
```

Although you don't really need the variables at that point! You could also use an array:

```
Dim C
C = Array(9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24)
For each v in C
```

Comment: Thank you!! I really appreciate your help~

Answer (score 0):

You're appending strings into the collection and later referring the same in Cells method.

While adding values to the collection

```
Set C = New Collection
C.Add "NU_C"
C.Add "FW_C"
C.Add "BI_C"
C.Add "B_C"
C.Add "DB_C"
C.Add "TL_C"
```

add actual values as

```
    Set C = New Collection
    C.Add 9
    C.Add 12
    C.Add 15
    C.Add 18
    C.Add 21
    C.Add 24
```

Hopefully this helps - Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I prefer to keep the column names so I don’t forget what I’m doing later on, but I appreciate your help :)